# How to organize nested axios calls to make them more readable?

Tags: vue.js, asynchronous, axios

I am a bit lost with async Axios calls.

I have nested Axios calls that works just fine, but I find it unreadable and I often lost myself in this code.

For now, I have something like :

```
axios.get().then((response) => {
    this.pbmInfos = response.data;

    axios.get().then((response) => {
        this.contactInfos = response.data;

        axios.get().then((response) => {
            this.clientInfos = response.data).catch((error) => console.log(error));

    }).catch((error) => console.log(error));

    axios.get().then((response) => {
        this.lastViewDate = response.data).catch((error) =>  console.log(error));

}).catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

(Of course, I didn't write URLs inside the get() for clarity)

For now, it may not seem too complicated but it is only a part of my calls.

I tried to factorize it in generic function so I could call it with different parameters, but I didn't succeed because every call need to assign the fetched data to a different variable, and some need to also call another call on success.

If you have any ideas I would love to read it.

Answer (score 5):

You can use async/await

```
async function fetchData() {
  let res1 = await axios.get("https://reqres.in/1");
  let res2 = await axios.get("https://reqres.in/2");
  let res3 = await axios.get("https://reqres.in/3");
}
await fetchData();
```

Comment: Depending on the use, you could also wrap that in `Promise.all([ ])` with await in front.

Answer (score 2):

As @protestator said, you can use async/await but you can also use promises, but in this way:

```
axios.get("https://reqres.in/1").then((response) => {
    return response.data;
}).then((response) => {
    return axios.get("https://reqres.in/2")
}).then((response) => {
    return axios.get("https://reqres.in/3")
}).then((response) => {
    this.lastViewDate = response.data
}).catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

In case of any doubt with Promises, this is my Bible:
https://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html

Bonus: more concise way:

```
axios.get("https://reqres.in/1")
        .then(response => response.data)
        .then(response => axios.get("https://reqres.in/2"))
        .then(response => axios.get("https://reqres.in/3"))
        .then(response => this.lastViewDate = response.data)
        .catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, where do the data fetched by "axios.get("https://reqres.in/2")" goes? And thanks a lot for your link :)

Comment: Returning the next promise within `then` is a good way of flattening the *pyramid of doom* but it would need a few extra lines to make sense. e.g. `this.contactInfos = response`. As currently written these examples are just throwing away the first two responses.

Comment: this is an oversimplified example, just to let @milky_way undestand a little bit more how this can work. 
the data fetched by `axios.get("reqres.in/2")` is implicitly returned thanks to the one line arrow function